# Replace string bash script with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am (unsuccessfully) trying to change my log format file.
I have input text which include:

```
VERSION = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
```

Cuz my client use split style with " delimiter so
I want to use sed command to convert input into:

```
VERSION = [ "1.1", "2.2", "3.3", "4.4" ]
```

I have tried this but it not works:

```
sed 's/^\(VERSION = \[\).*\(\]$\)/\1\", \"\2/'
```

Can anyone help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you match number and enclose them with double quotes in replacement:

```bash
s='VERSION = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]'
sed -E '/^ *VERSION =/ { s/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/"&"/g; s/\[/& /; s/\]/ &/; }' <<< "$s"

VERSION = [ "1.1", "2.2", "3.3", "4.4" ]
```

Here:

- `/^[[:blank:]]*VERSION =/`: Matches a line starting with optional spaces followed by `VERSION =` text
- `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?`: Matches an integer number or floating point number
- `"&"`: Wraps matched string with `"`
- `s/\[/& /`: Add a space after `[`
- `s/\]/ &/`: Add a space before `]`

Comment: Any another solution sir, cuz this: s/\]/ &/ made change all [ and ] in my file, that's wrong @@, please check it for me, thanks!

Comment: I missed `{ ..}` block. It should work now. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^VERSION =/s/[0-9.]\+/"&"/g' file
```

Match on a line containing `VERSION =` and surround all groups of digits and a period with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Its using `match` function of GNU `awk`, where I am using regex `(^[^[]*\[)([^]]*)(\])$` which creates 3 capturing groups and creates 3 values into array named `arr1` and then we are using 2nd value of it as per requirement to add `"` to before and after it, finally in this program printing all 3 values.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/uRqxRv/1) for mentioned regex, where it shows 3 of the capturing groups created by regex.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
{
  val=""
  match($0,/(^[^[]*\[)([^]]*)(\])$/,arr1)
  num=split(arr1[2],arr2,", ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    val=(val?val ", ":"") (s1 arr2[i] s1)
  }
  print arr1[1] val arr1[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

***OR*** to check if value starts from `VERSION` itself then try following:

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
{
  val=""
  match($0,/(^VERSION[^[]*\[)([^]]*)(\])$/,arr1)
  num=split(arr1[2],arr2,", ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    val=(val?val ", ":"") (s1 arr2[i] s1)
  }
  print arr1[1] val arr1[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sed -E '/^VERSION/{ s/([0-9.]+)/"\1"/g; s/\[(.+)\]/[ \1 ]/; }' input.txt
```

- `/^VERSION/{ X; X; }`, run multiple sed commands (X) on lines starting with VERSION
- `s/([0-9.]+)/"\1"/g`, add quotes to all version numbers
- `s/\[(.+)\]/[ \1 ]/`, add spaces next to brackets